# Need RTK-query mutation data in multiple components in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using React 18 with @reduxjs/toolkit 1.9.1.

On form Submit, a post API is triggered using RTK-mutation and used the response in the component. The page navigates successfully. Check the code below.

```js
const formSubmit = async (data) => {
  const payload = {
    ...
  };

  try {
    const response = await artistSearch(payload);

    if (response) {
      navigate("/artist-search-results", { state: { data } });
    }
  } catch (artistError) {
    ...
  }
};
```

using the relevant API

```js
export const artistApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "artistApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `...`,
    headers: { ... },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getArtist: builder.query({
      query: (uid) => `/getProfile/${uid}`,
    }),
    artistSearch: builder.mutation({
      query: (formData) => ({
        url: "ArtistListSearch",
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetArtistQuery, useArtistSearchMutation } = artistApi;
```

Now I am failing to use the `artistSearch` mutation response data in the component which is rendering just where the page navigates to.  IOW, I want to use `artistSearch` mutation response data in other components also.

I have tried via following code, but getting undefined in the console.

```js
const [
  artistSearch,
  {
    data: artistSearchResponse,
    error: artistError,
    isLoading: isArtistLoading
  }
] = useArtistSearchMutation();
console.log("artist search data is:", artistSearchResponse);
```

Comment: Where you defined your `useArtistSearchMutation()` function?

Comment: @Lokkesh The API slice generates the query/mutation hooks from the defined endpoints. See the last line of code in the second code snippet, the `artistApi` exports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used a specific cache key on the mutation such that other components using the same mutation can access the same cached results.

See [useMutation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usemutation): `fixedCacheKey`

> ```
> type UseMutationStateOptions = {
>   // A method to determine the contents of `UseMutationResult`
>   selectFromResult?: (result: UseMutationStateDefaultResult) => any
>   // A string used to enable shared results across hook instances which have the same key
>   fixedCacheKey?: string
> }
> ```

Example:

```js
const [artistSearch] = useArtistSearchMutation({
  fixedCacheKey: "artistSearch",
});

const formSubmit = async (data) => {
  const payload = {
    ...
  };

  try {
    const response = await artistSearch(payload).unwrap();

    if (response) {
      navigate("/artist-search-results", { state: { data } });
    }
  } catch (artistError) {
    ...
  }
};
```

```js
const [
  artistSearch,
  {
    data: artistSearchResponse, // should be same cached data from above
    error: artistError,
    isLoading: isArtistLoading
  }
] = useArtistSearchMutation({
  fixedCacheKey: "artistSearch",
});
```

Comment: Great, I am thankful to you.  Poor chatgpt doesn't know this yet instead giving me modestly reply for its lack of knowledge, it kept on circumventing and wasted my one hour.